# string to date time "hh:mm:ss" or "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss" format

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I try to convert a string like "hh:mm:ss" or "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss" but I didn't accomplish :(
Code like that :

```
public DateTime[] tarihSaat = new DateTime[documentRowCount]

string c = "27.12.2010 00:00:00"

tarihSaat[0] = DateTime.ParseExact(c, "dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

but it didn't work..Any suggestion?

Comment: Your code sample worked just fine for me - are you sure that `documentRowCount` is > 0 ?

Comment: How exactly did it not work? Did you get the wrong value? Did it crash?

Comment: Could you tell us what the progam *is* doing? Is it throwing an exception? Is it producing an incorrect date?

Answer (score 9):

You are doing everything in a correct way, but perhaps you need not `hh` but `HH` like this:

```
tarihSaat[0] = DateTime.ParseExact(c, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

`hh` is for 12-hour format, and looks like you are parsing from 24-hour format, so you need `HH`.

Answer (score 1):

This site has several examples of string formatting and time/date formats.

http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

DateTime.Parse("27.12.2010 00:00:00", 
               new CultureInfo("en-GB")).ToLongDateString();
```

// Gives you "Monday, 27 December 2010"